# Why is a property on a subclass, that returns a type consistent with the same attribute on the superclass disallowed

Tags: python, inheritance, mypy, typing, typechecking

```py
class Foo:
    bar: str

class Bat(Foo):
    @property
    def bar(self) -> str:
        ...
```

Given the above code, my typechecker (mypy) raises the following complaint:

```
error: Signature of "bar" incompatible with supertype "Foo"  [override]
```

This surprises me given that an instance of `Foo` or `Bat` will behave the same from the perspective of a caller accessing the `bar` attribute/property. What is the issue the typechecker is preventing by rejecting this code?

Comment: Which version of Mypy are you using? There was an issue (see [link1](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4125) and [link2](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8185) ) causing what you describe that has been fixed **as long as you also provide a setter for `bar`** . Which makes sense: `bar` in `Foo` is annotated as R/W... Whereas creating just a `@property` in `Bat` makes `.bar` RO.

Comment: Ahh, yeah I'd failed to consider the property wasn't writable. If you leave that as a proper answer I will mark this resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, @Josh! I hope my answer below is clear. Sometimes I write too much and end up overcomplicating things 

Comment: No that is a perfect level of detail. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on the comments to the OP:

Older versions of Mypy had some sort of issue/bug somehow tangentially related to this that led to some discussions on the project's GitHub: [Mypy disallows overriding an attribute with a property](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4125) and that should have be fixed on versions >=v0.990

There's also a discussion which feels much closer to the current's OP exposition: [overriding variable with property: error Signature incompatible with supertype](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8185)

In this second case, what happens is that...

```
class Foo:
    bar: str
```

...tells Mypy that `.bar` will be a writable attribute, whereas just declaring the `@property` in the child class `Bat`...

```
class Bat(Foo):
    @property
    def bar(self) -> str:
```

... would make the attribute read-only. The most straightforward fix, in this case, might be creating a setter for `.bar`.

The following code:

```py
class Foo:
    bar: str


class Bat(Foo):
    @property
    def bar(self) -> str:
        return "something"

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value: str):
        # ... actual setter code probably
        # for self._bar or something like that
        pass
```

Produces:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Please adjust your `self.bar = value` in implementation, it's in infinite recursion now.

Comment: Dangit!. This is what I get for editing 20 times trying to make it _"better"_ !! ‍♂️.  Nice catch! Thank you, @STerliakov

Comment: I’m entertained by the silly question of whether it violates the LSP that a read-write property can’t reliably be used as scratch space like an attribute can.